# Jquery/Ajax show/hide event order

Tags: jquery, event-handling, show-hide

I am trying to create a loading image when user clicks submit button. For some weird reason, it seems that the hide event gets executed simultaneously with the show event (I cannot see the loading image at all. I tried adding delay to hide but didn't work) If I remove the hide event, however, the loading image shows up just fine. Any ideas? Thank you so much for helping me.

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {
    $("#loading-popup").ajaxStart(function() {
        $(this).show();
    }); //show loading image
    //.....................
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        //.....................
        success: function(jsonData) {
            //.....................
            $("#loading-popup").delay(15000).hide(); //hide loading image
            //.....................
        },

    });
});
```

Comment: Honestly, if I had a connection so fast that I'd never see loading images, I wouldn't complain about it. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) without any parameter is a synchronous action similar to `.css('display', 'none')`. It is not an animation hence doesn't obey animation delays.

A simple solution is to simply pass `0` as the duration, so it triggers the animation version of `.hide()` which obeys the delay:

```
​$('#foo').​​​​delay(2000).hide(0);​
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CCwZm/)

Note that passing `0` as duration is buggy in some versions of jQuery so upgrade to 1.8.2 or the latest stable release of your version if you find issues. You can also use a `setTimeout` if you need a delay, even though that'd be just extra clutter.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out a complete noob. I had no idea about .hide(0)... It worked!! Thank you so much and have a great day

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#submitButton').click(function() {

  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: "json",
      beforeSend:  $("#loading-popup").show(); 
      //.....................
      success: function(jsonData) {
          //.....................
          $("#loading-popup").hide(); //hide loading image
          //.....................
      },

  });
});
```

Comment: Even though that didn't solve the show/hide problem, I realized it's much better indeed to use "beforeSend" Thank you ChuckE!